# Is there a word for the uncanny ability to find one's way home when extremely drunk?

Tags: single-word-requests

A small dispute broke out in the office today about this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I suggest "lucky". :)

Comment: Mathematicians call it [Pólya's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Higher_dimensions) (yes, it's a *theorem* that a drunkard will eventually return home, under a particular model realistic or not), but that's not what you were looking for. :-)

Comment: `Dumb Luck`?

Comment: ............. Darwin? >;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beerdar - as in beer-radar - although, that could just be something me and my student friends came up with.

Comment: Shouldn't "beerdar" refer to an uncanny ability to find beer?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, perhaps, although in my experience there is nothing uncanny about that.

Comment: don't see why - radar is not a way to find radio waves (it uses them for 'direction and ranging')

Answer (score 4):

One suggestion made during the dispute was "beer compass", but it was claimed that meant the same as "beer goggles".

Comment: If you believe Roger's Profanisaurus, _beer compass_ is the right answer; _beer goggles_ is not the same at all.

Comment: @Brian Nixon, thank you. I was inclined to suspect that.

Answer (score 3):

Not a one-word answer, but maybe "homing instinct"?

Answer (score 3):

Over here, we refer to this phenomenon as being on the "beer scooter."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a term for this ability specifically, but it can be considered an example of a homing instinct.